# Http request send child type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, enums

I've got an MVC web application that uses Angular at the javascript level.  I'm trying to make an HTTP request with an object that looks similar to this :

```
public class Template
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    //other properties
    public Enum Status { get; set; } //can be either of type InboundEnum or OutboundEnum
}
```

The problem is I have two possible `Enum` types (one called `InboundEnum` and one called `OutboundEnum`).  Normally, when I use angular's `$http.post()` the request properly converts other JSON into the correct `Enum` value since it has a specific `Enum` (like  `InboundEnum`).

The two `Enums`:

```
public enum InboundEnum
{
    Undefined = 0,
    Deleted,
    Saved,
    Pending,
    Completed,
    Cancelled
};

public enum OutboundEnum
{
    Undefined = 0,
    Deleted,
    Saved,
    Rejected,
    InTransit,
    Completed,
    Cancelled
};
```

Currently, the javascript object I'm sending looks like this:

```
{
    id: 'Id001`,
    status: 'Saved' //I know it's currently ambiguous which enum to use.  Solution?
}
```

How can I get the correctly typed values into the MVC API controller (like `InboundEnum.Saved` or `OutboundEnum.Canceled`)?  Is there a more elegant way of handling the proper type of `Enum` than also appending an `Template.EnumType` property and using switch statements to get the right `Enum`?

If I've got an anti-pattern going here please let me know that too.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) in your application then it can solve your problem. You don't have to pass the enum type in the request but have to specify certain attributes in your model on the server side.

```
public class Template
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    //other properties
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]
    public Enum Status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Sorry let me be more clear.  My problem is that the `Status` can be one of _two different Types_ known at the client javascript level.  I will edit my question to fix this.

Comment: But yes JSON.NET is an option.

Comment: In that case you definitely need to know what is the enum type so that you can try to parse it accordingly.